# Getting the correct url in router events

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular2-router

I have the following configuration of routes:

```
{ loadChildren: './public#PublicModule', path: '' },
{ loadChildren: './home#HomeModule', path: 'home' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
```

In some template (if it matters, let's call it *xxx.component.html*) I created a button to make some tests in my 404 route:

```
<button type="button" routerLink="unknown">Click here for unknown</button>
```

With this, I'm in route `home/xxx` and after press the button, it works, I mean it goes to 404 page, **however**, the following is returned for me:

```
NavigationEnd {id: 2, url: "/home/unknown", urlAfterRedirects: "/404"}
```

But I was expecting to get the **REAL** previous route (`home/xxx`), not the URL that I set in my button. Is there a way to achieve this?

**PS1:** I tried to use `pairwise`, but it only works after call the 404 route 2 times.

My 404 component looks like:

```
export class NotFoundErrorComponent {

  public previousUrl: string;

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.router.events
    .filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .subscribe((event: any) => {
      console.log(event);
      // this.previousUrl = event.url;
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: maybe use `NavigationStart` event?

Comment: @Maximus the event isn't the problem. I just removed the `filter` completely and it doesn't return me the REAL url that it comes from. In fact, IMHO, it's too complicated to work with routes in Angular. A simple thing like take the last visited route is toooooo complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens, step-by-step:

1. You are at `/home/xxx`
2. You navigate to `/home/unknown`
3. The router notices that you are on a path that should be redirected to `/404`, so it does that.
4. You are at `/404` and you check the previous URL which is `/home/unknown`.

I can think of 2 ways that this can be resolved:

1. Instead of redirecting `**` to `/404`, just set the 404 component to the path `**` in the router. You will stay on `/home/unknown` with the 404 component.
2. Implement a service of your own that tracks the url's visited in your application. For instance you could subscribe to the `Location` service from `@angular/router`, and track the URL's visited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't answer my question... I don't want my url to stay at `/home/unknown`, I just want to get the last (known) visited page, in this case, `home/xxx`.